# Package running in 64 bit, not running in 32 bit

Tags: ros, pcl, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all;

I have a package that uses PCL libraries  and that works perfectly in Groovy and Hydro, both in 64 bit machines.
In 32 bit machines, I can compile the package exactly the same way, without problems, but in execution it does not work.
The callbacks in it go indredibly slow, sometimes taking more than a minute, when in 64 bit they work perfectly fine.
Any possible causes for this package being stuck in 32 bit?
I am runnning Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit with Hydro and Groovy, and Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit with Hydro.

Thank you all in advance,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194348/package-running-in-64-bit,-not-running-in-32-bit/) by [altella](https://answers.ros.org/users/4898/altella/) on ROS Answers with karma: 149 on 2014-10-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) on 2014-10-07**:
Can you please post the error that you get during execution?

**Comment by [altella](https://answers.ros.org/users/4898/altella/) on 2014-10-07**:
It really gives no error... simply the callbacks are not executing at the rate specified

**Comment by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) on 2014-10-07**:
So are the callbacks executing at a lower rate or they are not executing at all? Are the two machines equivalent in terms of CPU, RAM etc?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-07**:
It's quite possible that the additional instructions and optimizations available in 64-bit mode make a big performance difference.

**Comment by [altella](https://answers.ros.org/users/4898/altella/) on 2014-10-07**:
I think they are executing, but a callback intended to run at 10 HZ, needs 80 seconds to enter for the first time

**Comment by [altella](https://answers.ros.org/users/4898/altella/) on 2014-10-07**:
The PC's are the same in terms of CPU and RAM, but it seems that the computation required for cluster extraction in PCL makes a HUGE difference btw 32 bit and 64 bit versions of the same OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved, it is a mere computation problem, of quantity of RAM and processing power of 32 bit vs 64 bit.
After downsampling the cloud, it goes just fine.

---

Originally posted by [altella](https://answers.ros.org/users/4898/altella/) with karma: 149 on 2014-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0